# IBM DataPower - How to handle HTML Response from openurl?

Tags: post, request, response, urlopen, ibm-datapower

I tried looking for the solution in the forum but I was unable to find something similar to what I'm trying to achieve. I have a gateway script in an MPG which kinda looks like this:

```
session.INPUT.readAsJSON(function (error, json) {
    if (error){
            throw error;
    } else {
    var SAMLResponse = json['SAMLResponse'];
    var RelayState = json['RelayState'];
    var urlopen = require('urlopen');
    var options = {
                            target: 'https://************.com/e32d32der2tj90g8h4',
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: { 'HEADER_NAME' : 'VALUE'},
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            timeout: 60,
                            sslClientProfile: 'ClientProfile',
                            data: {"SAMLResponse": SAMLResponse, "RelayState": RelayState}
    };
    urlopen.open(options, function(error, response) {
      if (error) {
            session.output.write("urlopen error: "+JSON.stringify(error));
      } else {
            var responseStatusCode = response.statusCode;
            var responseReasonPhrase = response.reasonPhrase;

            response.readAsBuffer(function(error, responseData){
              if (error){
                    throw error;
              } else {
                    session.output.write(responseData);
                    console.log(responseData);
              }
            });
      }
    });
    }
});
```

I'm doing a POST request and the response I get from the urlopen function is an HTML page, how to I display the contents of that page in my browser? I need that to initiate a process flow. am I going in the wrong direction here? what's the best way to POST to a URI and display it's response in DataPower?
with regards to my experience with DataPower, I just started learning, So I might not be familiar with many of the concepts.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

`session.INPUT.readAsJSON()` would indicate that you are receiving JSON data as the input (from the POST).

Since you are building this in a Multi-Protocol Gateway (MPGW) you need to set the Response type to `non-xml` if the response is HTML and if there is no backend call being made (other than the `url-open()`) you also must set the `skip-backside=1` variable.

Is the scenario as:

`JSON HTTP Request -> [MPGW] -> url-open() -> Backend server --|
      HTTP Response <-----------------------------------------|`

Or:

`JSON HTTP Request -> [MPGW] -> url-open() --| (skip-backside)
      HTTP Response <------------------------|`

If there is no backend call I would recommend building this in a XML Firewall (XMLFW) service instead and set it to "loopback" and `non-xml`.

If there is a backend and that is where you are sending your HTML from the `url-open()` then only MPGW Response type needs to be set to `non-xml`.

If it is the second option the you can just set the payload and headers in GWS and just call the target (`https://************.com/e32d32der2tj90g8h4`) as teh MPGW backside connection, no need for the url-open().